# Wireless Rickroll using Arduino

Tags: beginner, networking, arduino

This is a script I made for the ESP8266 that uses the Wi-Fi chip and creates a new Access Point every 5 seconds in order to display a message on WiFi lists on nearby devices that looks like this:

[image: Wifi list, showing "Never gonna give you up","Never gonna let you down","Never gonna make you cry","Never gonna say goodbye"]

The code is:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssids[] = {"Never gonna give you up","Never gonna let you down","Never gonna run around","Never gonna make you cry","Never gonna say goodbye","Never gonna tell a lie"};
const char* pass = "pass_goes_here";
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int currentssidno = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    const char* ssid = ssids[currentssidno];
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, pass);
    delay(5000);
    WiFi.softAPdisconnect(false);
    currentssidno = currentssidno + 1;
    if (currentssidno == 6) //please change this count if you change the amount of ssids
    {
      currentssidno = 0;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

The code is [also on GitHub](https://github.com/ardaozkal/Rickroll-Wifi).

How can I improve this code? This is my second or third project with Arduino and I pretty much made it in 15 minutes and looking at it now, some parts feels like dirty code (especially the part where I switch reset the SSID counter), how can I improve this?

Extra resources: [Wi-Fi Library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi), [ESP8266 Arduino Core](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No particular comment on the Arduino-specific or Wifi-specific stuff, but here:

```
currentssidno = currentssidno + 1;
if (currentssidno == 6) //please change this count if you change the amount of ssids
{
  currentssidno = 0;
}
```

Two things. First, you can rephrase this conditional logic as simply

```
currentssidno += 1;
currentssidno %= 6;  // please change this, etc.
```

or equivalently

```
currentssidno = (currentssidno + 1) % 6;  // please change this, etc.
```

depending on where you'd prefer to [repeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the name `currentssidno`. (I'd probably rename that variable to `i` and then use the latter form.)

Secondly, don't hard-code magic numbers like `6`, if you can express them as "non-magic" numbers such as "the size of this particular array I've got".

```
// Put this macro in your toolkit. You'll use it frequently.
#define DIM(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

/* ... */
currentssidno = (currentssidno + 1) % DIM(ssids);
```

Now you no longer need the comment, because the code no longer has that weird subtle dependency on the length of the `ssids` array. It Just Works, no matter what `ssids` you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

One small suggestion:

`setup()`, is, as described, only meant to run once, at startup.

Once `setup()` is finished, `loop()` will be called in an infinite loop.

So you could remove your `while(true)` loop from `setup`, and move the code to `loop`:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define DIM(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

const char *ssids[] = {
    "Never gonna give you up",
    "Never gonna let you down",
    "Never gonna run around",
    "Never gonna make you cry",
    "Never gonna say goodbye",
    "Never gonna tell a lie" };
const char *pass = "pass_goes_here";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  static int currentssidno = 0;
  const char *ssid = ssids[currentssidno];
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, pass);
  delay(5000);
  WiFi.softAPdisconnect(false);
  currentssidno = (currentssidno + 1) % DIM(ssids);
}
```